# Tap, tap, stomp, stomp

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the expression "Tap, tap, stomp, stomp!" mean in the following text (not available online) from the description of arcade games:

> **Tap, tap, stomp, stomp!** You will always find someone tapping and
> stomping away on the dance machines at the entrance of the arcade.
> Pick a song by your favorite artist and tap along to the rhythm – with
> these games, your fingers stomp.

Also, I am confused as to the said expression is in an imperative mode or it is just a description of the sound made by the player.

The excerpt is from a marketing text related to apps.

Comment: Don't forget to mention the source!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a description of the sounds that can be heard at "the dance machines at the entrance of the arcade."

Compare the onomatopoeic chorus of [the Woody Guthrie song "Bling Blang:"](https://www.woodyguthrie.org/Lyrics/Bling_Blang.htm)

> Bling blang, hammer with my hammer
> Zingo zango, cutting with my saw

The lyrics describe the sounds to be heard when using tools. Similarly "Tap, tap, stomp, stomp!" is just setting the scene for the rest of the app description. It is not an imperative.